# At what level should security be implemented in a social network web application?

Tags: php, security, web-applications

I am developing a social web application in php/mysql, I would like to hear your advice about what would be a better way to implement security. I am planning something like this:- At the presentation level, I restricting the user to see only those items/content he is eligible to see with the rights he is eligible & at the database level, whenever my data is read/ written or updated I verify that the person has rights to such interactions with that part of data. So for each action there is 2 layers of security one at the view level & another at the database level. Would double checking be much overhead ?

ofcourse this handles only with the internal security issues ..

Answer (score 1):

I would say any app that needs even a modicum of security has to do it this way.

We have several applications that work in a similar manner.  We test for authorization both at the application and the database levels.  Among the benefits is that we can have multiple loosely related apps utilizing the same datastore with the exact same security model enforced.

Another benefit is that it is much harder to compromise the database in the event an application is pwnd.

Along these lines we don't even allow the apps to directly manipulate tables (selects/deletes/etc).  Instead, everything goes through stored procedures.  All proc's take a userid (non-guessable) and internally validate that the user is allowed to perform the requested function.  If not we fail silently.  A side benefit is we are immune to sql injection.

Besides allowing the database to be self contained and enforcing it's own authorization checks, even if they were able to acquire a valid super user account it becomes time consuming to do large swaths of damage.  Given that we actively monitor db and app usage we have the capability to detect and stop an attack in progress thereby limiting any exposure.

Remember, it's only paranoia if they aren't out to get you. And they almost always are.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a good way to handle the situation, but why do the users need to have so many different levels of eligebility, can't you just restict them to the info that is in their account.